# Cactus looks weird

Tags: cactus

[image]

Hello, my cactus is turning brown and whiteish at the base. It is not exactly softer at the base compared to the rest of the cactus. Not sure if this is root rot or something else. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cactus normally get some discoloration or corking low on the stem naturally. Your plant doesn't really look like corking, however. Have any conditions changed? Repotted, changed location anything that might affect the plant?

It almost looks like mold in the picture provided. You might try an anti-bacterial, fungicide spray and see if that improves things.

Something to keep in mind, cactus need free draining soil and a pot with better than average drainage. Some airflow doesn't hurt either.

BTW, I think your cactus is a Parodia leninghausii, as near as I can tell from the one picture.